# IOS/CGSize: How to crop image to fill space

Tags: ios, cgsize

I am trying to follow a tutorial that provides a category for resizing an image.  But the code is crashing on the following line:

```
CGSize mainImageSize = self.size;
```

The debugger at the breakpoint says:

```
size    CGSize  (width=142, height=142) 
mainImageSize   CGSize  (width=2.121995791459338E-314, height=2.121995791459338E-314)
```

Frankly, I don't know what to make of the above:

Here is the source file of the category:

```
-(UIImage *) createThumbnailToFillSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize mainImageSize = self.size;//LINE WHERE IT CRASHES

    UIImage *thumb;

    CGFloat widthScaler = size.width / mainImageSize.width;
    CGFloat heightScaler = size.height / mainImageSize.height;

    CGSize repositionedMainImageSize = mainImageSize;

    CGFloat scaleFactor;
    // Determine if we should shrink based on width or hight
    if(widthScaler > heightScaler)
    {
        // calculate based on width scaler
        scaleFactor = widthScaler;
        repositionedMainImageSize.height = ceil(size.height / scaleFactor);
    }
    else {
        // calculate based on height scaler
        scaleFactor = heightScaler;
        repositionedMainImageSize.width = ceil(size.width / heightScaler);
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGFloat xInc = ((repositionedMainImageSize.width-mainImageSize.width) / 2.f) *scaleFactor;
    CGFloat yInc = ((repositionedMainImageSize.height-mainImageSize.height) / 2.f) *scaleFactor;

    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(xInc, yInc, mainImageSize.width * scaleFactor, mainImageSize.height * scaleFactor)];
    thumb = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return thumb;
}
```

And here is how it is called.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        //thumbnail stuff
        CGFloat side = 71.f;//was 71 in Kuh book
        side *=[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
        UIImage *thumbnail = [chosenImage createThumbnailToFillSize:CGSizeMake(side, side)];
        self.imageView.image = thumbnail;
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on what is causing crash.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: BTW - you want `71`, not `71.f` because CGFloat is a double on some platforms. Let the compiler do the conversion for you.

Comment: There is no error in red but on running the program crashes at the line indicated above,  the line is highlighted in green as thread 1, breakpoint 2.1 and the debugger gives the messages shown.

Comment: Delete your breakpoint so the app doesn't stop or simply click the "continue" button in the debugger.